# How to use react-native-google-mobile-ads with Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo app that works well. Now, I would like to add a few ads before publishing it on Play Store in order to make a few bucks. Expo says their in-house ads package is deprecated and that I must use `react-native-google-mobile-ads`.

Because `react-native-google-mobile-ads` is a native package, it means I need to perform special tasks, and it's a bit unclear on how to proceed from here.

From what I've understood, I need to:

- install `expo-dev-client` and `react-native-google-mobile-ads`
- add `react-native-google-mobile-ads` in the app.json 's `expo plugin`

```js
"expo": { "plugins": ["react-native-google-mobile-ads"]}
```

- add my adMob api key in `app.json`

```js
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
"android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
"ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
```

- create an account on `https://expo.dev` and run `eas login` in my terminal
- then `run eas build --profile development --platform android` to generate a build
- since expo-go won't work anymore because of the native package, I won't be able to run the app on a real phone. I will have to finish the development on an android simulator by running `expo start --dev-client` and press `a` to open the app on the android emulator.
- then add the code to display the ads.
- Once it's done, run `eas build --platform android` to create a build
- follow the long process to upload my first build to the Play Console
- Publish it as a beta app, send the link to adMob review.
- Once adMob says all's good, I can publish the app for good on the PlayStore.

It's not a smooth process... I don't know why Expo decided to remove such a common package! Can someone confirm to me this is the right process? Or maybe there is a simpler approach, with a different library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution. Here are the steps to take:

- `yarn add react-native-google-mobile-ads`
- add your adMob credential in `app.json` (out of the expo object)
- suscribe to Expo's EAS.
- run `eas login` in your terminal and enter your credentials
- make sure you're correctly logged-in by running `eas whoami`
- make sure you have Android studio and SDK 31 installed
- make sure you have Java 11 Zulu installed
- run expo install `expo-dev-client`
- if you want to build for ios, run `eas device:create`. Else, move on to the next line.
- run `eas build --platform android --profile development --local` (you may replace `android` by `ios` or just run the command without the `--platform` flag. I added `--local` because the cloud build wasn't working for unknown reasons). This will create a build on your machine.
- drag and drop the build (`.apk` for android) directly on your simulator. This will install it on it.
- run `expo start --dev-client`
- your app is now running on your phone. Congratulations. The fast refresh is enabled and you may have some fun.
- once you're happy with the coding, start the build again.

Comment: Hi, my local eas build is always failing with "/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:29:85-105 Error:

[stderr]  Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT@value value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:29:85-105

[stderr]  is also present at [:react-native-google-mobile-ads] AndroidManifest.xml:19:13-34 value=(false)." Any idea why this happens? :/

Comment: Sadly, no. These build tools are constantly changing and introducing breaking changes. It's just tiring in the long run lol.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a solution, this is a workaround.

Comment: I am getting this error-- Android builds are supported only on Linux and macOS `eas build --platform android --profile development --local`

Comment: I've only tested this method on osx.